# apache2, vhosts and servername directive

Tags: apache-2.2, hosts, virtualization, virtualhost

I'm running an apache development environment on my ubuntu desktop machine.
When I start apache, I get the error

```
"apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.0.1 for ServerName
 ... waiting apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.0.1 for ServerName"
```

I attempted to fix this by adding a line to my apache.conf:
    servername myhost

This eliminates the error message. However, with this configuration, requests for vhosts are not honoured. Only the default host is accessible.

Is there a way I can eliminate this error, and have vhosts ?

Answer (score 1):

Undo your modification in `apache.conf` and change your `/etc/hosts` file to:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.1.1 mycomputername

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1 ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
ff02::3 ip6-allhosts
```

Erasing the duplicated alias in the first line should solve the problem. Apparently `/etc/hosts` can only map one FQDN per line.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your solution.

Does this mean that my vhosts have to be technically on a different network?

Comment: I'm not sure to understand your comment :) The solution above solves the apache warning and has no impact on vhost. Did you try it? Do you still have problems?

Comment: Hi.

I guess I'm just a little confused about the ip address that corresponds to the hostname in the snippet that you provide. 

I know that 127.0.0.1 refers to 'this host'.
But I've never heard of using a '127.0.1.1' address.
But, this  is probably just me missing something simple.

Anyway, I did give it a shot, but I'm afraid that I get the same result: the error message goes away, but the vhost is no longer accessible.

Comment: *... this is probably just me missing something simple* : yes (and this is actually how the `/etc/hosts` looks like in Karmic, this is how this bug has been fixed). *I'm afraid that I get the same result: the error message goes away, but the vhost is no longer accessible.* : I can guarantee that this would be for another configuration mistake, I have fully working vhost with this setup.

Comment: Regarding your first question, vhosts can be ip-based **or** name-based. So no, they don't have to be *on a different network*.

Answer (score 0):

This is a serverfault question I believe, but did you do `sudo a2ensite` and activate the conf file, then `apache2ctl graceful` ?

You can do `apache2ctl -S` to see which virtualhosts are enabled. Also ensure that you updated `/etc/hosts` so that you have an entry pointing to `127.0.0.1`.

Comment: Yes. I have made sure to enable the vhosts with a2ensite.
I usually restart apache with /etc/init.d/apache restart

apachectl -S shows that the vhosts are indeed enabled, even though I can't see them.

Answer (score 0):

> requests for vhosts are not honoured

Create a file called `virtual.conf` inside `/etc/apache2/conf.d/`.

The file should contain:

`NameVirtualHost *`

Reload apache (`sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 reload`) and virtualhosts should work.

Comment: When I do this, I still get the original error. I also get another error message that outputs itself repeatedly"

[code]
apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.0.1 for ServerName
[Tue Nov 10 13:06:04 2009] [error] VirtualHost *:80 -- mixing * ports and non-* ports with a NameVirtualHost address is not supported, proceeding with undefined results
...
[/code]

Answer (score 0):

you can refer this [Virtual Hosting](http://smallmailman.wordpress.com/2009/11/08/installing-apache-2-2-and-virtual-hosting/). Hope it helps. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding ServerName vars to your Virtualhost configs.

For example, if you have the root ServerName var set to "www.myhost.com" under each  you would set ServerName to "virtualhostname.myhost.com"